# Disable tap-to-click on  Aspire 4730z

Tags: windows-vista, touchpad, acer-aspire

I have an  Aspire 4730z(Windows Vista home premium), and it seems to not have the "touchpad" option in the control panel, and the mouse options don't let me disable tap-to-click.

How would I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to remove both the Alps driver and the Synaptics Touch Pad driver. Then, I reinstalled the Alps driver from the Acer site. The UI controller for the Alps driver let me disable it.

What a *nightmare*. This should have been easy.

Answer (score 2):

As already mentioned the method for XP will work, however you need to have the [Synaptics Touch Pad](http://www.synaptics.com/support/drivers) driver loaded for your machine. The driver for your notebook can be downloaded [here](http://support.acer-euro.com/drivers/downloads_gd.html) or you can download it from the Synaptics link directly.

Comment: +1, this is the first thing I download on any laptop, and it seems like ALL laptops use this driver. Hate tap to click so much, how do people live with it?

Comment: I love tap to click. On my linux installation, single tap is left click, two finger tap is right click, and three finger tap is middle click. How do people not like it?

Answer (score 1):

This is on XP but I think it will be close to what you need to do. I am at work without access to Vista

[pictorial](http://picasaweb.google.com/ldsmith104/Touchpad?feat=directlink)

Answer (score 1):

This is hard to find, but very easy to do once you know how!

1. Go to Start then Control Panel;
2. On the top right corner, select "View by Small Icons";
3. Double-click on Mouse;
4. Select the Device Settings tab;
5. Click on the Settings button;
6. Click on the Tapping item;
7. Unselect "Enable Tapping";
8. OK
9. OK
10. Close

I hope you found this before you went CRAZY trying to make the touchpad work.  I wish Acer would disable tapping as the default.